# passing parameters from groovy to python ( Jenkins job)

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

I am using groovy to call a python in my Jenkins job. i would like to pass few parameters also to the python and i need to use those in the python

I am calling the python like below

```
result = sh(returnStdout:true , script: '#!/bin/sh -e\n' + 'python test.py').trim()
```

The parameters i need to pass are jenkins build job parameters.

Can you suggest a solution to this problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cmd = """#!/bin/sh -e\n' + 'python test.py ${JENKINS_VAR_1} ${JENKINS_VAR_1}"""
result = sh(returnStdout:true , script: cmd).trim()
```

Assuming you already have the code in python to access the argument.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. It is working fine now.